# Wordpress authentication for rest API with nonces using python

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use the Wordpress Rest API from python and I am struggling with authentications.
I am aware that there are various plugins available for various authentication methods, but I want to use "vanilla" authentication and not rely on any plugins.

So I am able to login via python (on my local dev instance):

```
import requests

username="admin"
password="password"
wp_login="http://localhost:8888/wp-login.php"
wp_admin = "http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/"


headers1 = { 'Cookie':'wordpress_test_cookie=WP Cookie check' }
datas={
  'log':username, 'pwd':password, 'wp-submit':'Log In',
  'redirect_to':wp_admin, 'testcookie':'1'
}

session.post(wp_login, headers=headers1, data=datas)

# This works and returns 200
resp = s.get(wp_admin)
```

Now, to use any Rest-API endpoints I need to create a nonce of type "wp_rest". How do I do that?

All examples I can find are in javascript and use:

```
wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
```

But how do I do this in python (or any other language/http library)? How do I get the 'wp_rest' nonce?

Comment: WordPress 5.6+ has a built-in support for [application passwords](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/), so how about using it?

Answer (score 0):

As @SallyCJ mentions, [application passwords](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/) are built in to WordPress since version 5.6, so if you can use those, you should.

If application passwords are not enabled, or you do not want to use them for whatever reason, then you can scrape the `wp_rest` nonce from the response of e.g. wp-admin/post-new.php. I wrote some Python code that does that.

It depends on the `requests` and `beautifulsoup4` libraries. To install them:

```
pip install requests beautifulsoup4
```

Here is the code:

```py
import argparse
import os
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class BaseUrlSession(requests.Session):
    """Extend Requests' Session class with the ability to specify a base URL"""

    def __init__(self, base_url=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_url = base_url

    def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):
        joined_url = urljoin(self.base_url, url)
        return super().request(method, joined_url, *args, **kwargs)


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--base-url", required=True, help="The base URL of the WordPress site")
    parser.add_argument("--user", required=True, help="The username to log in with")
    return parser.parse_args()


def log_in(session: BaseUrlSession, username: str, password: str) -> None:
    response = session.post(
        "wp-login.php",
        data={"log": username, "pwd": password, "wp-submit": "Log In"},
        allow_redirects=False,
        timeout=10,
    )
    if response.status_code != 302 or "Set-Cookie" not in response.headers:
        raise RuntimeError("Login failed")


def get_wp_rest_nonce(session):
    response = session.get("wp-admin/post-new.php", timeout=10)
    response.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    js_elem = soup.find(id="wp-api-request-js-extra")
    if not js_elem:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Could not find the script containing the wp_rest nonce"
        )
    js = js_elem.text.strip()
    match = re.search(r'"nonce":"([0-9a-f]+)"', js)
    if not match:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Could not parse the script containing the wp_rest nonce"
        )
    return match.group(1)


def main():
    args = parse_args()
    session = BaseUrlSession(base_url=args.base_url)
    log_in(session, args.user, os.environ.get("WP_PASSWORD", ""))
    session.headers["X-WP-Nonce"] = get_wp_rest_nonce(session)
    # Further requests made using the session will include the nonce you fetched


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```